# Print all variables available in a Smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

How do you print all variables available in the context of a Smarty template? Something like the Django debug trace that lists everything being passed.

Thanks

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use `{debug}` [From the manual](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.debug.tpl):

> `{debug}` dumps the debug console to the
>   page. This works regardless of the
>   debug  settings in the php script.
>   Since this gets executed at runtime,
>   this is only able to show the assigned
>   variables; not the templates that are
>   in use. However, you can see all the
>   currently available variables within
>   the scope of a template.

`$debugging = true` must be enabled in your settings or class, and site popups must be unblocked to see the window

Comment: Remember to allow popups when using {debug}. Browser blocks debug info popup by default.

Comment: still helpful in 2014 (might be for older versions of smarty though)

Comment: `{debug}` is available in both Smarty 2 and 3

Comment: why nobody mentions that `$debugging = true` must be enabled in your settings or class, and site popups must be unblocked to see the window

Comment: Sometimes, `{debug}` causes memory limit because of huge amount of data to display. Is there any function to call from template file to display the list of defined variables only?

Comment: `{debug}` proves to be a nice surprise!

Answer (score 13):

```
var_dump($Smarty->_tpl_vars);
```

From the Smarty code :)

Answer (score 7):

Updated answer for Smarty 3: [getTemplateVars](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.get.template.vars.tpl)

```
// If no parameter is given, an array of all assigned variables are returned. 
$all_tpl_vars = $smarty->getTemplateVars();
```

Answer (score 0):

$all_tpl_vars = $smarty->getTemplateVars();
var_dump($all_tpl_vars);

//before pushing to the template

exit;