# how to get year as string from timedate in tpl file?

Tags: php, smarty, assign

in tpl file 
for example

```
{$listings.activation_date} = 2013-12-20 20:46:10
```

and when use this:

```
[[$listings.activation_date]]=12.20.2013
```

how to  use :

```
{assign var=foo value='12.20.2013'}

{if $foo == [[$listings.activation_date]]}
```

this does not work and throws back this error:

```
Fatal error! Your request can not be executed!
```

and another question is how to get today time in tpl file.

Answer (score 3):

To get date in tpl file in your php file use this

```
$smarty->assign('currentDate', $date("Y-m-d"));
```

in tpl file

```
<h1>{$currentDate}</h1> //prints <h1>2013-12-21</h1>
```

And why are you using [[]] brackets in tpl code?

why not use  like this

```
{assign var=foo value='12.20.2013'}
{if $foo == $listings.activation_date}
```

Comment: tanx, but i have 2 problem: i don t know where add this code  $smarty->assign('currentDate', $date("Y-m-d"));  and 2: the brackets is  default code for this cms and change 2013-12-20 20:46:10 to 12.20.2013 .  i don t know how to get current year with that.:(

Comment: smarty have two files to make one page, .php file and .tpl file. i.e home.php and home.tpl you put $smarty->assign('currentDate', $date("Y-m-d"));  in home.php and <h1>{$currentDate}</h1> in home.tpl. in ur case it might be index.php and to get current year in home.php call date() and use substr method or explode() to get year. and assign that yeat to smarty template variable. all the logic or bussiness logic must be created and handeled in .php file. use .tpl to only make html

Comment: How can I see the all stuffs pass by smarty php to tpl file like as currentdate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716916/print-all-variables-available-in-a-smarty-template

Answer (score 0):

I finally found myself

in search_result.php

```
$tp->assign('currentdate',date('Y-m-d'));
```

in tpl file :

```
{assign var=foo value=$listing.activation_date|date_format:"%D"}

    {if $foo==$currentdate|date_format:"%D"}
```